# Помогите решить проблему с установкой React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Устанавливал всё как в ролике/npx create-react-app my-app
[Затем вот такая ошибка] (https://prnt.sc/tld5xe)

Comment: Эм, так это не установка nodejs, а создание react app. Судя по ошибке нода у вас есть и работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Проблема решена"
Нужно было установить Git